# Accessing an object element containing a colon in js

Tags: javascript, xml, json

I parsed some xml into json, using xml2js and got elements containing colons:

```
obj = { "data:example":"smthing"};
```

Do you know a way to access these elements straight from json ?
Or any tricks maybe ?

Thank you !

Comment: `var x = obj["data:example"]`

Comment: `JSON` is a serialised version of a JavaScript object, so you probably mean "from JavaScript", not "from JSON".

Comment: I meant JavaScript indeed, thank you !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply access the property like this:

```js
obj = { "data:example":"smthing"};
alert(obj['data:example']);
```